# public_suffix not getting installed while running bundle install jekyll github-pages

Tags: ruby, bundle, jekyll, github-pages

I have a blog of mine in jekyll and I want to publish it on github-pages. 
Taking reference from here:
https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages.
but I am getting this error while running bundle install

```
Gem::InstallError: public_suffix requires Ruby version >= 2.0.
An error occurred while installing public_suffix (1.5.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install public_suffix -v '1.5.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

below is the details of my gem env
gem env :

```
    RubyGems Environment:
    - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.3
    - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.6 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 336) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
    - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/2.1.0
    - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby2.1
    - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
    - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/ashwin/.gem/specs
    - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
    - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/2.1.0
     - /home/ashwin/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.1.0
 - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.1
 - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
 - GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - REMOTE SOURCES:
 - https://rubygems.org/
 - SHELL PATH:
 - /usr/local/heroku/bin
 - /usr/local/sbin
 - /usr/local/bin
 - /usr/sbin
 - /usr/bin
 - /sbin
 - /bin
 - /usr/games
 - /usr/local/games
```

Answer (score 3):

Just like you my ruby version was correct, but the fix for me was reinstalling bundler.

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Comment: This fix worked for me (though in a Dockerfile without `sudo`); for some reason after running a `gem update --system`, bundler itself started having issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing without `sudo`.

I've had the same issue after upgrading Ruby to 2.2.3 with `rbenv` (which is [installed without admin rights](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04#ruby-rbenv)).

After having upgraded, I ran `sudo gem install github-pages`, which resulted in the above error. Running `gem install github-pages` worked just fine.

Then, trying to have Jekyll serve my page, I ran `bundle exec jekyll serve`, which told that there were some bundles missing. `bundle install` fixed that too, and `bundle exec jekyll serve` worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `gem install public_suffix -v '1.5.1'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'public_suffix' (= 1.5.1), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: i also tried with sudo gem install github-pages :

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing github-pages:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/gem_make.out

Comment: I guess we have a problem with ruby. I suggest you to use rbenv (https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and try to update to an upper ruby version like 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this command solves it.

`sudo gem install github-pages -v 33`

Then run jekyll.

`bundle exec jekyll serve`

[See here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/286)

Comment: Try Reinstall bundler: `$sudo gem install bundler`. Then try `$bundler install`  at your directory, where `Gemfile` is.

Answer (score 0):

In the past i've also had issues with installing github pages or Jekyll dependencies because there is a space somewhere in the full path to your project folder and apparrently some of the dependencies cant handle spaces in filenames.

Most recently this seems to have been happening to me with `public_suffix` version 4.0.5 where a space in my username causes it to break

[image: Errno::EACCES: permission denied @ rb_sysopen]

This has also happened with [http_parser](https://github.com/tmm1/http_parser.rb/issues/47)